# Handling Arguments in C++ not working

Tags: c++, command-line, arguments

I am using this code:

```
    int handleArgs(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc <= 1)
      {return 0;} 
    else 
      { // If no arguments, terminate, otherwise: handle args

        for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {

          if (argv[i] == "-a" || argv[i] == "--admin") 
            {           // If admin argument
              char *pwd = argv[i+1];            // i + 1 b/c we want the next argument; the password

                if(pwd == "1729" || pwd == "GabeN") 
                 {                  // Verify Password

                cout << "Sorry, console feature unavailable.\n" << endl;// Will replace with console function when I get to it

                } 
               else 
                {
                  cout << "Wrong/No passkey, bruh.\n" << endl;
                }       // If the password is wrong


           } 
          else if (argv[i] == "-v" || argv[i] == "--version") 
           {        // If user asks for version info

            cout << "You are running\nDev0.0.0" << endl;            // Tell the user the version


           }  
             else if (argv[i]==" -h" || argv[i]=="--help") 
              {

                cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " -[switch] argument(s)\n";
                cout << "   -a,  --admin        Open console view. Requires password\n";
                cout << "   -v,  --version      Print version and exit\n";
                cout << "   -h,  --help         Print this message and exit\n" << endl;

                } 
               else {
                 cout << "Is you dumb?\n    '" << argv[0] << " --help' for help" << endl;       // Insult the user
                    }                       
        }
    }
  return 1;
  }
```

However, every time I give it an argument, I receive the invalid argument message (the last else statement):

```
Is you dumb?
    'main --help' for help
```

I'm new to C++, and I have no idea what I am doing (wrong). Could anyone provide me with some helpful insights? Thanks

--FracturedCode

Comment: Can you show me how are you passing arguments...just for reference..

Comment: @MGP int main(int argc, char *argv[])

Comment: @MGP handleArgs(argc, argv);

Comment: I mean how you made call....just for eg. filename arg1 arg2....some like this...right?

Comment: `argv[i] == "-a"` and such does not do what you think it does. You need to use `strcmp` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv` is an array of C-Strings (`char*`). You are using `==` and comparing memory addresses instead of the overloaded `==` operator that C++ strings provide. You should use `strncmp` to compare your strings (it's safer than `strcmp`). Although it doesn't matter much here as you are comparing with a literal, which guarantees one of them will end.